# Semantic Interpretation of the axiom of restricted separation

Tags: set-theory, definition, first-order-logic, model-theory, axioms

In a follow up to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4710123/164699) to a previous question, I want to see if I have a correct understanding now of the semantic interpretation of the axiom of restricted separation. As a side note I'm also interested in how to avoid ambiguity when writing about models of set theory (like sets definable in the structure versus sets as the actual objects of the theory, as well as the use of $\in$ both formally and informally in the metalanguage.) Ok. This is what I think

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a structure in the language of set theory. Then the axiom of restricted separation implies that for any formula $\phi(x)$ and $\mathbf{a}$ in $|\mathcal{M}|$ that if $S\subset |\mathcal{M}|$ is such that for all $x$:
$$x \in S  \; \iff \; \mathcal{M} \models \phi(x) \wedge x\in \mathbf{a}$$
Then there exists a $\mathbf{b}$ in $|\mathcal{M}|$ such that for all $x$:
$$x\in S \; \iff \; \mathcal{M} \models \; x \in \mathbf{b}$$
Is that correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's basically correct (although I'd strongly encourage you to include *parameters* in your formulas; while [technically unnecessary](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/rds/ZFC_without_parameters.pdf), that's nontrivial). However, there's no reason to introduce $S$: just say "there is some ${\bf b}\in\vert\mathcal{M}\vert$ such that $$\{x\in\vert\mathcal{M}\vert: \mathcal{M}\models x \in{\bf b}\}=\{x\in\vert\mathcal{M}\vert: \mathcal{M}\models x\in{\bf a}\wedge \varphi(x)\}."$$ Incidentally, note that the set on the left hand side is often conflated with ${\bf b}$ itself; obviously *this is technically improper*, but it is common. (When multiple models with possibly-overlapping domains are considered, I find notation like "${\bf b}^\mathcal{M}$" to be a happy medium between confusion and tedium.)

Comment: Thanks. But does the $\in$ symbol in $x\in |M|$ mean the same thing as $x\in \mathbf{b}$? I thought the first is the metalogic and the second is the syntactic level. I just don't see how to judge the best way to phrase things.

Comment: @Ari Technically they're different, and if you want to carefully distinguish them you can use $\in$ vs. $\varepsilon$, and I've seen this done occasionally - usually with "$\in$" referring to the metatheoretic notion and "$\varepsilon$" the syntax-object. But they are commonly conflated in practice (whether or not that's a good idea is a different question).